# Mechanizeによるスクレイピングでsearchに渡す引数が分からない

Tags: ruby

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Rubyにて、Mechanizeというgemを使って、下記サイトをスクレイピングし、添付の赤枠部分のテキスト、URLを取得し、取得したテキスト、URLを出力できるようにしたいと考えております。

赤枠部分のデータ取得がうまくいかず、困っております。
アドバイスいただけると幸いです。

※該当のサイトURL
https://www.jpnsport.go.jp/nishigaoka/tabid/127/Default.aspx

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

下記コードの（）内に入れるコードが不明です。

```
latestArticles = current_page.search('　　　')
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```rb
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows IE 9'

CodeZineTopURL = 'https://www.jpnsport.go.jp/nishigaoka/tabid/127/Default.aspx'
current_page = agent.get(CodeZineTopURL)

latestArticles = current_page.search('ここにいれるコードが不明')

latestArticles.each do | article |
  puts "#{ article.inner_text }: #{ CodeZineTopURL + article[:href] }\n"
end
```

#### 試したこと

こちらの記事を参考に、下記コードを入れてみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。
https://qiita.com/Atsuyoshi-N/items/096620127da45f99179d

＞試したコード

```
dnn_ctr541_Event_grdPresentMonth > tbody > tr:nth-child > td:nth-child > a
dnn_ctr541_Event_grdPresentMonth tbody tr td
'//*[@id="dnn_ctr541_Event_grdPresentMonth"]/tbody/tr/td'
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

ruby 2.6.5

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 質問編集ありがとうございます！大変助かりますm(_ _)m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記コード記述し、希望の要素を取得することができました。

```
latestArticles = current_page.search('table.event-calendar td a')
```

Comment: 問題が解決した場合は、回答の承認操作を実施してください : https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers